# run install-package without it prompting to install nuget

Tags: powershell, nuget

I'm trying to install an msi using install-package on a group of remote computers, but I kept getting the interactive prompt to install nuget.  Is there any way to turn off that prompt?

```
install-package software.msi

The provider 'nuget v2.8.5.208' is not installed.
nuget may be manually downloaded from
https://onegetcdn.azureedge.net/providers/Microsoft.PackageManagement.NuGetProvider-2.8.5.208.dll and installed.
Would you like PackageManagement to automatically download and install 'nuget' now?
[Y] Yes  [N] No  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "Y"):
```

Comment: Do you want it to install the package provider?

Comment: @BendertheGreatest No.  Some other software in an msi.

Comment: Can't say I use `Install-Package` often but I don't think it can install raw MSI files. You'd want `msiexec` for that.

Comment: @BendertheGreatest no it works, you can install and uninstall with uninstall-package, see what's there with get-package.

Comment: Well, TIL. Yeah I figured this one out, I'll leave a fresh answer for the `Install-Package` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you CAN install raw MSIs from `Install-Package`. In order to not get prompted for the Nuget provider installation, as well as prevent other prompts from happening, running `Install-Package` with the MSI provider:

```
Install-Package -ProviderName msi -Force software.msi
```

Not saying it's impossible, but at the surface I don't see a way to pass additional arguments into the MSI for Powershell 6 and later (Powershell 5.1 does have an `-AdditionalArguments` parameter). So keep this in mind if you have MSI installers that do need additional parameters passed in. If I find a way to do this I will update the answer.

Comment: At least in ps 5.1 install-package has an -additionalarguments parameter.

Comment: Good catch, I was looking at the PS 6 documentation for `Install-Package` and it seems `-AdditionalArguments` was removed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for `msiexec`, not `Install-Package` as the latter installs a specially formatted package from a repository.

If you want to install `software.msi` with `msiexec`, you can do so like this:

```
msiexec /i $pathToSoftwareMsi /qn
```

If you want to write the installation log to a file, you can add logging parameters:

```
msiexec /i $pathToSoftwareMsi /qn /l*v $pathToOutputLogFile
```

## Explaining the Parameters

- **/i**: Tells `msiexec` to install the package
- **/qn**: the `q` tells `msiexec` to execute with no user interaction. The `n` sets the UI level to `No UI`. These are instrumental for ensuring the installer doesn't ask for input during an unattended installation.
- **/l*v**: Log the output to the specified file. `/l` indicates you want to output the log to a file, and the `*v` indicates all logging options plus verbose.

You can see the full range of options by running `msiexec /?`

Answer (score 0):

Nuget install command:

```
install-packageprovider nuget -force
```

Answer (score -1):

Install-Package is used to install NuGet packages in the context of a .NET project mostly.

To install an msi, you can just run the msi or use msiexec. I found a good explanation here: https://powershellexplained.com/2016-10-21-powershell-installing-msi-files/

Comment: You should add some context around your link around installing packages with `msiexec`

Comment: Not true.......